# Bash script normal user to Root

Tags: linux, bash, root

I have some question. I'm trying to create some bash script to automatically some task. I need to do the first step of the task as normal user, and su - to be root to finish the task.

I've been wondering if there is a way to do that? Until now i'm only been able to start the bash as normal user, complete the first step, ask for su - password, but after it connect as root, the script stop.

Is it possible to proceed with the bash after been logged as root?

Thank you in advance.

ps : If I'm not precise, or if you need some information, feel free to ask, I'll do my possible to correct those mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the answer, just have to use the su - -c "" cmd.

Exemple :

```
tar /home/me /dev/null

su - -c "yum update -y"

tar /home/me /dev/null

su - -c "
yum install xterm -y
yum clean-all
yum remove xterm -y

"
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `sudo somecommand` instead of trying to switch users? Your user will need to be in the 'wheel' user group (depending on your system) to do that.

`su` changes the environment (user variables etc.) so, though I haven't tested this, you probably can't do it in a shell script.

Example:
Your shell script was

```
#Do these commands as a normal user
echo "Hello World"
cat ./somefile

#Do these commands as root
su -
echo "Hello again"
cat /etc/somesystemfile
```

try changing it to

```
#Do these commands as a normal user
echo "Hello World"
cat ./somefile

#Do these commands as root
sudo echo "Hello again"
sudo cat /etc/somesystemfile
```

Comment: No I didn't, I often forget about the sudo. Thanks I'll try this.

Comment: some command don't work with sudo (well, at least I get error) like cd...

Comment: @Anarko You shouldn't have to run commands like CD with sudo as they don't require root permissions, so you can CD to a directory as your normal user then use `sudo` to run commands. I think.

Comment: Sudo is meant for executing a single command. Using consecutive sudo commands and changing path in one of them, with cd, is not going to work. I agree with other posters: execute the whole script with sudo and forget about sudo'ing the individual commands inside your script.

Comment: @wzzrd I agree, or if some commands *have* to be run as the normal user (not sure why) split the shell script into two parts, one to run as normal user and one to run as root.

Comment: I forgot that. Like I said, I often forget that I can use sudo, and so the way to use it. my bad. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Start the process as root, then execute normal user tasks with `su (-) user -c ..command..`, and finish it as root. This way it won't even ask for password.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a specific command you wish the script to be able to execute as root, while it's running as another_user then you should use sudo.

Configure sudo to allow another_user to execute the specific command, something like this in your sudoers file,

```
someuser ALL=/path/to/specific_command
```

and then in your bash script use,

```
sudo /path/to/specific_command -some -args
```

If you want your bash script to run lots of commands as root, or run general commands such as mv or cp you might want to come at this from a different angle.  Write the script so that it runs as root (in root's crontab for example), and have it execute the non-root commands using '*su - someuser*' because root can do that without putting passwords in.